# Calculating Big O time complexity of mouse vs text-entry algorithms

Tags: algorithm, macros, big-o

I am trying to decide if it's faster to use a macro to open a group of bookmarked links or to just do it manually.

**Manual Algorithm:**

1. Switch to or open Chrome. How long this takes depends on how you open or switch to applications.
2. Find bookmark menu bar with your eyes.
3. Move the mouse to the bookmark menu bar with your hand (mouse/trackpad). This is different from finding it with your eye.
4. If the bookmark is not in the first level, then find the correct root parent folder. The problem here is that you may not remember it and will have to do some looking around.
5. Select the correct root parent folder with your mouse.
6. Find X number of correct sub-parent folders with your eyes. Same
   problem as #4.
7. Select X number of correct parent folders with your mouse.
8. Right-click on the desired group folder
9. View the 3 options on how you will open the bookmarks {Same
   Window, New Window, Incognito Window} with your eyes.
10. Choose from the 3 options with your brain of course, lol.
11. Make the selection corresponding to your choice with your mouse.

So that's the first algorithm. Perhaps it can be reduced in some way depending on context.

**Macro Algorithm:**

1. Hit a keyboard shortcut trigger of your choosing
2. Type the minimum number of characters that uniquely identifies the
   bookmark group. Of course you have to remember the group's name.
3. Hit Return

The actual algorithm can be found here: https://forum.keyboardmaestro.com/t/how-to-create-a-macro-to-open-a-group-of-tabs-in-a-browser/7447/7)

I'm obviously biased because I created the macro, but I'm looking for some technical assessment that proves one is faster over the other.

**Update**
I understand this doesn't stand out as a computational problem, so please make and list assumptions in order to make it so.

For example, Manual step #3, moving the mouse, involves X and Y coordinates, so would that not be exponential?

Also, then Manual steps 4-8 involve navigating a hierarchy, which is similar to navigating a tree structure.

Comment: These instructions are not algorithms. The notion big-O complexity is not applicable to them.

Comment: @n.m. Then the problem needs to be specified differently. How do you suggest?

Comment: I have no idea how to phrase this as a computational problem. To me it sounds like human sciences (psychology, physiology, ergonomics, whatever).

Comment: It's not too far from computational. Maybe some assumptions need to be made to get there. I'm not up on my algorithmic complexity but each step could be broken down to some level of big-O and then it's just a matter of finding the bottleneck, right? For example, #3, moving the mouse, involves X and Y coordinates, so would that not be exponential?

Comment: Then steps 4-8 involve navigating a hierarchy, which is similar to navigating a tree structure.

Answer (score 1):

The Big O notation is used for problems that have a variable size (often denoted with N), and, importantly

- such that N is large enough (more often in the thousands or millions than in the hundreds),
- doesn't tell anything about actual costs, but only how they grow with N.

For instance, knowing the Quicksort is O(N Log N) and BubbleSort is O(N²), does not allow you to tell which is the fastest for N = 10. Not at all. (And by the way, it is likely that one will be the fastest on some cases and slowest on others.)

---

Saying that O(N Log N) is faster than O(N²) is a naive and wrong statement. For small N, the Big O notation is completely useless.

For your problem, what you can do is to establish exact complexity formula (detail the count of operations and assign true durations to them). This can be difficult and it is easier to benchmark a few representative cases.